# How to get list or table element in masterpage of birt report to get all rows?

Tags: java, javascript, report, birt

I'm unable to insert table or list element in master page of my birt report Without these two elements i'm nt able to get all data rows on header of master page.
But **i need all data rows in header of masterpage of Birt report Its my requirement **.So help me to know how to get all data rows in header of master page?

Answer (score 3):

You put table and list elements in the "Layout".

The "Master Page" defines header and other attributes, it is not used for the body of your report.

Comment: thanx.. but i need to get all rows on header of master page.is there any other alternate to get rows on master page header?

Comment: The master page is an element of a BIRT report.  Create a section in the layout to meet your requirements, and call it the master page. I assume you have some requirement that says the report must look like "something". You can use Page breaks to have one part of the layout be a "Master Page".

Comment: My requirement is to display all rows of column in header of master page which should display on all pages of my Birt report.Give ur solution briefly.

Comment: The simple way is to add a grid to the master page, then paste in labels of the column names.  There is another solution where you repeat the column headers on each page break, but that occurs indepenent of the master page (i.e. in the layout and table design).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the same XY problem I had: I'm making an invoice and want the billing address on every page "header". The masterpage is inappropriate for this, because it is generated at a stage in the pipeline without access to the data. You can pass variables to it, but the scope crept to where I was passing eighteen variables. Here's another way:

1. Build the nice header in the body: a grid of three tables, each with five detail rows, whatever. Build a nice report body, something crazy wild, doesn't matter.
2. Make a dataset that returns one record.
3. Add a list to the body. Bind the list to dataset. Add a data field to the list detail, bound to that field.
4. Hide the data element of the list.
5. Move your header to the list header. Move the report body elements to the list detail.
6. Profit: That list header will repeat on every page the list detail shows up on.

I probably got the idea from the actuate forums, but I can't find which thread now. The point is birt is amenable to some pretty circuitous composability. With this technique, plus tables with parameters bound to that list data element, I was even able to emit several multipage invoices in the same pdf. There's a caveat to my enthusiasm: page values didn't reset on those invoices for me.